# Want to implement nanomsg in android using its java binding jnanomsg getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, jna, nanomsg

I am trying to implement nanomsg in android and i got java bindings from this link : http://niwinz.github.io/jnanomsg/ after this dependency
compile 'jnanomsg:jnanomsg:0.4.3' . It was returning me this sun/jna/libjnidispatch.so was not found.

After some time i figured out ".so" file which is required for jna is missing later i got all required ".so" from this link

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/dist after that i copied libjnidispatch.so file to app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libjnidispatch.so and

i loaded the so file by System.loadLibrary("jnidispatch") after that app application got compiled.
  When i try create a object for  `ReqSocket sock = new ReqSocket();` I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                  at nanomsg.Nanomsg.getSymbols(Nanomsg.java:35)
                  at nanomsg.Nanomsg.<clinit>(Nanomsg.java:48)
                  at nanomsg.Nanomsg$constants.<clinit>(Nanomsg.java:51)
                  at nanomsg.reqrep.ReqSocket.<init>(ReqSocket.java:13)
                  at com.example.nanomsg.onClick(MainActivity.java:125)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The SecurityManager implementation on this platform is broken; you must explicitly provide the class to register
                  at com.sun.jna.Native.getCallingClass(Native.java:1295)
                  at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1252)
                  at nanomsg.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:30)
                  at nanomsg.Nanomsg.getSymbols(Nanomsg.java:35) 
                  at nanomsg.Nanomsg.<clinit>(Nanomsg.java:48) 
                  at nanomsg.Nanomsg$constants.<clinit>(Nanomsg.java:51) 
                  at nanomsg.reqrep.ReqSocket.<init>(ReqSocket.java:13) 
                  at com.example.nanomsg.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:125) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
```

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Could anyone can please help me what mistake i am doing here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run with system property `jna.debug_load=true` and `jna.debug_load.jna=true` to get more runtime loading information.

Comment: Hi technomage, i edited my post please check it once and thanks for the response.

Comment: This might help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/mlUcaZZYkgQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that `Native.register()` without a class argument requires a context class loader which can successfully report the calling class.  Android does not provide one.

Without that, `Native.register()` requires you to explicitly identify the class you want to register.  Unfortunately, it may be impossible to even load the class defined by nanomsg if their `register` is in a `static` block.  You would need to copy their class definition (which may be small or large) and register your own mapping.  Or ask them to patch their `register` call to work with Android.

See also [jna-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/ScvXwjx2AtM).

Comment: @rajesh-n: Hey, is the resulting code available on a branch somewhere?